# Problem with a black screen below the topTabBar

Tags: react-native, scroll, react-navigation, feed

I'd like to be able to animate the top of my toptabbar when the user scrolls up, but when I do it, the whole page moves up and I get a black stripe on my page.

I don't want to have this tape anymore and I want my page to be complete.

For this I put at your disposal my browser and my screen the other is empty. I can't increase the screen size in my TopReelTabNavigtor. I can't find anything

```
const TopReelTab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator<ReelStackParamList>();

export function TopReelTabNavigator() {
  const [scrollDirection, setScrollDirection] = useState("null");
  const height = Dimensions.get("window").height;
  const imageTranslateY = useState(new Animated.Value(0))[0];

  useEffect(() => {
    if (scrollDirection === "bas") {
      Animated.timing(imageTranslateY, {
        toValue: -60,
        duration: 300,
        useNativeDriver: true,
      }).start();
    } else {
      Animated.timing(imageTranslateY, {
        toValue: 0,
        duration: 300,
        useNativeDriver: true,
      }).start();
    }
  }, [scrollDirection]);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView edges={["top"]} style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "red" }}>
      <Animated.View
        style={{
          transform: [{ translateY: imageTranslateY }],
          flexDirection: "column",
          flex: 1,
          width: "100%",
        }}
      >
        <Animated.Image
          source={require(".././assets/images/test/Logo.png")}
          style={{
            alignSelf: "center",
            width: 45,
            height: 45,
            opacity: imageTranslateY.interpolate({
              inputRange: [-60, 0],
              outputRange: [0, 1],
            }),
          }}
        />
        <TopReelTab.Navigator
          initialRouteName="Foryou"
          screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
            tabBarPressColor: "black",
            tabBarPressVisible: true,
            tabBarLabel: ({ focused }) => {
              return (
                <MaskedView
                  maskElement={
                    <Text fontWeight="bold" fontSize={18}>
                      {route.name}
                    </Text>
                  }
                >
                  <LinearGradient
                    colors={["#E53AD9", "#FF630B"]}
                    start={{ x: 0, y: 0.4 }}
                    end={{ x: 1, y: 0.6 }}
                  >
                    <Text
                      fontSize={18}
                      fontWeight="bold"
                      color={focused ? "transparent" : "white"}
                    >
                      {route.name}
                    </Text>
                  </LinearGradient>
                </MaskedView>
              );
            },
            tabBarIndicatorStyle: {
              backgroundColor: "#E53AD9",
              alignSelf: "center",
            },
            tabBarStyle: {
              backgroundColor: "#000",
            },
          })}
        >
          <TopReelTab.Screen name="Following">
            {(props) => (
              <ReelFollowingScreen
                {...props}
                setScrollDirection={setScrollDirection}
              />
            )}
          </TopReelTab.Screen>
          <TopReelTab.Screen name="Foryou">
            {(props) => (
              <ReelForyouScreen
                {...props}
                setScrollDirection={setScrollDirection}
              />
            )}
          </TopReelTab.Screen>
        </TopReelTab.Navigator>
      </Animated.View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

my screen

```
type Props = {
  navigation: NativeStackNavigationProp<ReelStackParamList, "Foryou">;
  setScrollDirection: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>>;
};

const EVENTS = graphql(
  `
    query events {
      events {
        id
        category
        likesCount
        isLiked
        description
        name
        file {
          url
        }
        author {
          username
          avatar {
            url
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `
);

export default function ReelForyouScreen({
  navigation,
  setScrollDirection,
}: Props): JSX.Element {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(EVENTS);
  const [index, setIndex] = React.useState("");
  const height = Dimensions.get("window").height;
  const prevOffsetRef = useRef(0);
  const flashListRef = useRef<FlashList<Event>>(null);

  const verification = (event: Event) => {
    const parts: string[] = event?.file.url.split(".");
    const extension: string = parts[parts.length - 1];

    return (
      <EventCard
        event={event}
        shouldPlay={event.id === index}
        navigation={navigation}
      />
    );
  };

  const onViewableItemsChanged = useCallback(
    ({ viewableItems }: { viewableItems: ViewToken[] }) => {
      if (viewableItems && viewableItems.length > 0) {
        setIndex(viewableItems[0].item.id);
      }
    },
    []
  );

  const handleScroll = (event: any) => {
    const yOffset = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;
    const margin = 10;

    if (yOffset <= 0) {
      setScrollDirection("null");
    } else if (yOffset < prevOffsetRef.current - margin) {
      setScrollDirection("haut");
    } else if (yOffset > prevOffsetRef.current + margin) {
      setScrollDirection("bas");
    }
    prevOffsetRef.current = yOffset;
  };

  return (
    <Box bg="blue.900" flex={2} height={height + 60}>
      <FlashList
        ref={flashListRef}
        data={data?.events as Event[]}
        extraData={index}
        renderItem={({ item }) => verification(item)}
        estimatedItemSize={500}
        maxToRenderPerBatch={5}
        updateCellsBatchingPeriod={100}
        windowSizeprop={5}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        onViewableItemsChanged={onViewableItemsChanged}
        viewabilityConfig={{
          itemVisiblePercentThreshold: 70,
        }}
        onScroll={handleScroll}
      />
    </Box>
  );
}
```

I'd like a tab bar that rises when the user scrolls down the page, while keeping the page complete.